# JavaFX - How to use multiple same type of event handlers on a single node

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, singular

I've got 2 ListViews (A and B) of the same base type. What I need to implement is: 
- user drags items from A, drops them into B
- user drags items from B, drops them into B(rearrangement).

The changes has to be saved in an sqlite table. 2 different sql query runs, so the drag and drops must have a different outcome.

If I do 2X B.setOnDragDropped, can I differentiate the 2 depending on where did the drag start?

Thanks for your help, much apprich folks

Comment: found the solution: if (event.getGestureSource() == B){....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `setOnDragDropped(...)` twice on the same node, the second handler will replace the first one (it is a `set` method, and works the same way as any other `set` method: it sets the value of a property).

You need something along the lines of

```
listViewB.addEventHandler(DragEvent.DRAG_DROPPED, e -> {
    // handler code here...
});
```

You can determine the source of the drag inside the handler with

```
    e.getGestureSource()
```

and see which node it matches to determine the course of action.